Modify json reader with no access to editing the reader class
We are working on a localization mod for Il2cpp game. Initially, to apply localization to the game, we were launching this code that has all properties and lines from source JSON file. We have private Dictionary<string, GameClass> __instance._dic that is written in the game. The question is... Is there a way to modify the JSON value class without touching the said class in the game code? I want to add some of my own lines to the JSON file and make them readable in this class.
Me and my friend have tried to extend the class by making new ones: CustomClassList and CustomClass. I'm completely lost at this point.
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText("Myfile.json");
GameClassList Localization = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<GameClassList>(jsonString);
foreach (var applyChange in Localization.assets)
{
    __instance._dic[applyChange.name] = applyChange;
}

(The names of classes are placeholders)
The game either doesn't see the CustomClass and CustomClassList or, when the code is modified, throws an error in the game that CustomClass cannot be converted to GameClass. There's no compiling errors on my side, and conversion errors on the side of my friend.
EDIT:
Since I am the only one left to work with this problem in the team, I guess I can show more code for better understanding. I also give up on placeholding the names of our custom classes, too.
That's the custom child class for adding new fields and making a List<> with them.
{
    [Serializable]
    public class NicknameData : *GameClass*
    {
        public string? runame;
        public string? ruNickName;

        public NicknameData() {}
        public static *GameClass* HELP(NicknameData data)
        {
            var PLEASE = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            *GAMECLASS* assetData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<*GameClass*>(PLEASE);
            return assetData;
        }
    }
    [Serializable]
    public class NicknameDataList : *GameClassList*
    {
        public new Il2CppSystem.Collections.Generic.List<NicknameData> assetData;

        public NicknameDataList() { }
    }
}

And that's the Harmony code my friend did (and I have modified) before the version above:
public static string nicknameJSON = File.ReadAllText(*JSON_FILE.json*);
public static NicknameDataList nicknameDataList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NicknameDataList>(nicknameJSON);

[HarmonyPatch(typeof(StoryData), nameof(StoryData.Init))]
[HarmonyPostfix]
private static void StoryDataInit(StoryData __instance)
{
    *GameClassList* blyahaMuha = nicknameDataList;
    
    foreach (var nicknameData in blyahaMuha.assetData)
    {
        __instance.*_dic*[nicknameData.name] = (*GameClass*)NicknameData.HELP((NicknameData)nicknameData);
    }
}

Since this code has pieces of game's code, I have changed some names to placeholders to not get in trouble. The changed values are surrounded with "**".
I hope this edit makes the question and the problem more understandable.

What is JsonSerializer?  Is it from System.Text.Json?

Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as suggested in [ask].  You wrote The game either doesn't see the CustomClass and CustomClassList or, when the code is modified, throws an error in the game that CustomClass cannot be converted to GameClass. but you don't show us how to see those errors for ourselves.  Instead you're basically asking us to reverse-engineer your code from your error description, then debug the error.  That's very hard, and rarely results in helpful answers.  If you can show is how to reproduce the error, we're much more likely to be able to help.

You can't add properties to the C# class called GameClass just by adding properties to your .json file.  You have to provide a full description of all the properties of the class you want to deserialize in your C# code and the JSON must fully describe an object of that type.  Otherwise you may be looking for polymorphic deserialization (<-- search term for you)  Or you can deserialize it as dynamic.

make them readable in this class - how? You said you can't modify the class so the code will never use whatever you add even if you can add it. Even if you edit the json to contain more game class instances and get them into the dictionary the game still won't realise they're there unless it's doing something like iterating the dictionary and showing you a menu. You need to explain in a lot more depth what you're trying to achieve

If you want to change the existing data, go ahead- read the file, change all the localisation text so it's leetspeek or whatever and rewrite the json file so when the game reads it in it changes all its UI. You can't add stuff though

My friend, who was helping me with describing the issue had given up the whole idea, so I'll have to explain the whole thing from my own perspective only now.
I've had an idea of adding the new fields to json with the ability to change the output value for the game (the json contains names and titles of characters for the Story part) from our language to English, if our custom fields are lacking. For now we've used the original, Korean name/title fields, which is very confusing when the game gets updated and new charas appear.

The said GameClass class lacks "Init" function or any other function beside GameClass(), which, as my lacking knowledge goes, is not enough for Harmony to add/edit. Plus, it's ciphered by Il2cpp, which gets little hard to understand and change. But aside from that, the GameClassList seems to be the same: simple and crypted. From what is understandable in the old DLL of the game, the needed Dictionary(which has string and GameClass) is placed in a third class, StoryData, and hidden as private.

I may be lacking knowledge of c# and coding in general, but by logic, I thought that it could possible to extend the class and it would be working since the CustomGameClass, which is a child of GameClass, should be considered a GameClass, but alas, the game does not think so and gives the System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to Il2CppSystem.Collections.Generic.List1[*Name of the Parent Class*]. Path: $.assetData | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 16. error. I will add the codes for Custom Class to the body of the question, since it's only mine problem now

In the end, with the help of some acquaintances  I've looked at the situation from a different view. Instead of trying to make NicknameData act as its parent, we changed the way the names and titles in the game are called.
Even though now the game deserializes the said JSON twice, it's pretty safe working with the times when the character array lacks the needed lines.
Now the Nickname Data looks like this:
    [Serializable]
public class NicknameData : *GameClass*
{
    [JsonPropertyName("runame")]
    public string? runame;

    [JsonPropertyName("ruNickName")]
    public string? ruNickName;

    public NicknameData() { }

    internal static NicknameData Create(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
    {
        var result = new NicknameData();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                break;
            }
             if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                string propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();

                if (propertyName == "name")
                {
                    result.name = reader.GetString();
                }
                else if (propertyName == "runame")
                {
                    result.runame = reader.GetString();
                }
                else if (propertyName == "ruNickName")
                {
                    result.ruNickName = reader.GetString();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

Beside that, I was given the custom converter which is, unlike built-in ones, working without sending errors of inability to converse into parent class or, which is more frequent, the Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error.
It's quite long so I'll edit the link of the converter into the answer once we push the code update onto our localization GitHub.
Either way, thank you, those who tried to help me! Now the localization idea which haunted me for weeks has come to fruition and I feel really happy and relieved.
